# How to zoom text in Scrivenings mode without changing the actual font?

Tags: software, tools, scrivener

I'm using Scrivener for Windows (latest version). I set out to read my entire novel in Scrivenings mode. However, the text is a bit small for easy reading.

I see a Zoom toolbar at the bottom of the screen. It currently says 135%. The size of the text does not change when I change the zoom using that toolbar. "View / Zoom / Zoom In" also does not change the display size.

Is there any way to get Scrivenings mode to display larger without changing the actual font?

Comment: Scrivener zooms fine in Scrivenings mode in my version of Scrivener. If you still have the problem after closing Scrivener and starting it again, maybe you better contact Literature & Latte support.

Comment: @what: You're using the toolbar at the bottom of the main Scrivener window? You're on the Windows version?

Comment: Yes (toolbar at bottom) and no (Mac).

Comment: As another person using the latest version of Scrivener on Windows, I cannot duplicate your problem. Zooming works fine for me. As user5645 said, if closing it and opening it again and turning your computer off and back on again doesn't work, try contacting support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not intended behaviour. The zoom function should work the way you were expecting it to work.

This is simply a bug. If you see such a behaviour and it is not solved by closing and restarting the software and your PC you should first see if there is a newer version available to check whether that version fixed a bug like the one you are seeing or not.

If those steps didn't work you should file a bug report on [their bug reporting site](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/bug-reporting) to make the company behind the software aware of this bug.

Be sure to include the important information, such as:

- the version of the software you are using
- the operating system
- the settings you changed from the standard
- a detailed step-by-step instructions on how to reproduce the behaviour

This is something where you need the help of the company behind the product.